# How to Store Visual Studio's Debug Configuration in Source Control

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio's debug configurations are stored in the `.user` file which is user specific and traditionally ignored by source control.

I am interested in the working directory parameter. I need it to be consistent across programmer's machines and it have the value of `$outDir` instead of the default `$ProjectDir`.

How can I resolve these contradictions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to the end of the vcxproj before the `</project>` tag:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>c:\same\for\everyone</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I just checked it on 2010.

Visual studio will still show $(ProjectDir) in the IDE because I guess it populates it with whatever it finds in the `.user` file, but during building tasks it seems to process the `.user` file after the vcxproj; without an override in the `.user` it seems to accept what's set in the vcxproj.

Note that if you put this *at the end of* the vcxproj as I suggested, it is necessarily after the import of `Microsoft.Cpp.props` which is all that's important as @Claytorpedo points out

Comment: Still works in VS 2019. Specifically needs to be defined under `<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />`.

Comment: @Claytorpedo you should make this an answer. The fact that it's dependent on the position in the file is extremely important! People keep filing bugs that this doesn't work because CMake tries to write this (and I bet fails to write it to the right spot), and MS keeps closing the bugs. I added an "answer" here, but adding your comment as an answer to SO I think would also be a good idea: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/268817/debugger-no-longer-respects-localdebuggerworkingdi.html

Comment: This answer still works for VS 2022

Answer (score 6):

Adding to @zeromus's answer by request.

You can set the working directory in the vcxproj like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>c:\same\for\everyone</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, for it to work, it needs to be defined *after*

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
```

If you define `LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory` before that import, it will be overridden back to the default location.

You can also use relative paths. For instance in one project, I have it set like:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>..</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

so that it starts from one directory above the vcxproj file.

Tested in VS 2019.