# Where is VS Configuration Properties stored

Tags: c++, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-2019

I'm running a C++ solution filled with a number of projects. I have set each project up so that when running out of the IDE, the Debugging->Working Directory points to $(ProjectDir)..$(Configuration) per my projects requirements. All is well regarding that, but i cannot find where that change exists, therefore i can't check it in.

Does VS store that off in a file that relates to the project/solution file? or is it hidden somewhere else where each developer needs to set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those settings are stored alongside your C++ project, in a separate file named `<your_project_name>.vcxproj.user` (which is an XML-file as well). For the particular setting you mention, look at the `LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory` element there.

Typically, you would exclude `.user` files from version control, to allow developers to maintain their own, independent debugging configuration. But perhaps in your case you could agree on a particular working directory team-wide and push the `.user` file as well.

EDIT: However, there seems to be a better solution: to utilize the `.vcxproj` file itself (instead of the `.user` file) and just store the `LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory` element there, by manually editing the project file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38300298/1458097

Comment: Good answer, beat me to it. Is that a better solution though? For example, if you change the setting in the property pages, what happens then? Also, if a particular dev wants her own `.vcxproj.user` file she can have one, if you stick to doing it the official way

Comment: @PaulSanders - you’re not wrong here. In this particular environment, the directories are pretty finicky which is why I’m trying to tighten them down. We’ve been dealing with “nuance” for quite a long time and I’m now fixing it.